# Create 3 quarter donut chart using Google Chart library

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization, ng2-google-chart

I'm trying to make a donut chart like below using google chart library:

[image]

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106784/google-halfdonut-pie-chart-is-it-possible-to-set-total-percentage) article that makes half donut, but didn't find the code to create the one in my image.
Can anyone help?

Comment: I guess, your tag should be `google-chart` not `google-chat`

Comment: Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 3):

Read here https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#removing-slices
It simply says donut charts are just pie charts with `pieHole` values between 0 and 1. To remove some slices, it says

> To omit a slice, change the color to 'transparent':

```
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Pac Man', 'Percentage'],
          ['', 75],
          ['', 25]
        ]);

        var options = {
         legend: 'none',
          pieSliceText: 'none',
          pieHole: 0.4,
          pieStartAngle: 0,
          pieEndAngle: 180,
          tooltip: { trigger: 'none' },
          slices: {
            0: { color: 'yellow' },
            1: { color: 'transparent' }
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donut_single'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

Comment: Thanks, Canbax. This is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pieSliceText`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart) and [`pieStartAngle`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart) with an empty data field;

```js
google.charts.load('visualization', '1.1', {
    'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    const data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Skils', 'Skills level'],
        ['React', 6],
        ['HTML', 4],
        ['PHP', 2],
        [null, 12]
    ]);

    new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).
    draw(data, {
        title: "My Skills",
        slices: {
          3: {
            color: 'transparent'
          }
        },
        pieHole: 0.5,
        width: 600,
        height: 600,
        pieSliceText: 'value',
        pieStartAngle: 270,
    });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, This is helpful.